# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource userdata.hbm.xml

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate

This is my directory structure:

[image]

These are the errors:

[image]

I am trying my first hibernate program and i am getting this error. My program simply enters username, password and email in the database. I have created a POJO user.java, a UserManager.java, and two xml files, one for config and other for hibernate mapping. I have tried on this error for so long and still no solution.

This is my user.java:

```
    package com.csc.training.Twitter;

    public class User {

        String username;
        String password;
        String email;
        int user_id;
        Date joined;

public Date getJoined() {
        return joined;
    }
    public void setJoined(Date joined) {
        this.joined = joined;
    }

        public int getUser_id() {
            return user_id;
        }
        public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
            this.user_id = user_id;
        }


        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }   
    }
```

UserManager.java

```
package com.csc.training.Twitter;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;

public class UserManager {

    public void registration() {

    Configuration config=new Configuration();
    config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory factory=config.buildSessionFactory();

    Session session=factory.openSession();

    Transaction transaction = (Transaction) session.beginTransaction();

    User user = new User(); 

    user.setUsername("fname2");
    user.setPassword("lname2");
    user.setEmail("def@def.def");

    session.persist(user);

    transaction.commit();

    System.out.println("User Id : " + user.getUser_id());

    session.close();
    System.out.println("Employee update successful...");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserManager um=new UserManager();
    um.registration();
}
}
```

And these are the xml files..

userdata.hbm.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-mapping>
       <class name="com.csc.training.user" table="userdata">
          <id name="user_id">
             <generator class="increment"></generator>
          </id>


          <property name="username" column="username" type="string"/>
          <property name="password" column="password" type="string"/>
          <property name="email" column="email" type="string"/>
          <property name="joined" type="timestamp" column="joined"/>

       </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-configuration>
       <session-factory>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect">
          org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
          com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
       </property>

       <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
       <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost/twitter
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            root
       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
          root
       </property>

       <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
       <mapping resource="userdata.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

My database is twitter and the table name is userdata. userdata contains user_id (int, primary key,auto increment), joined(timestamp),username,email,password.
Can anyone tell me what the error is? Thank you very much!

Comment: joined column is not exist in your POJO class

Comment: Added. Tried with 'String joined'. Also with 'Date joined'.No change. Same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DTD declaration in hibernate configuration files is not correct.

In `user.hbm.xml` file it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

For `hibernate.cfg.xml` file it should be:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

After doing these changes make sure they are in classpath when you run your `UserManager` program.

Comment: @user3387006, Edit your question and add a screenshot that shows the folder structure of your project, also show the files under classes directory. Post the complete stacktrace of exception you are getting to the question. Also the hbm.xml mapping says `user` but the java class name is `User`, check that.

Comment: Added the directory structure and error its showing. Please check. Also I changed the hbm.xml mapping to user but its stil the same error. It cant access the hbm.xml.

Comment: @user3387006, now the error says connection timed out while reading hibernate.cfg.xml file as it is not able to find the DTD file. Please add a screenshot that shows the jar files that you have placed in classpath. Generally the DTD should be part of hibernate jar files so hibernate checks the Jar files for DTD, if it is not there then it tries to connect to Internet to read the DTD file.

Comment: @user3387006, Also please add the complete stacktrace of exception as a text to your question instead of screenshot.

Comment: @user3387006, Its good to see that the issue is fixed, can you please tell us how you have fixed the connection time out issue?

Comment: i downloaded the dtd files again and loaded them in the project. No idea how that made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

Take property **joined** as Date type and configure **HBM** file with the following tag

```
<property name="joined" type="timestamp" column="joinedDate_time"/>
```

Change doc-type of HBM file to beloe

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

and CFG fiel with

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Comment: And where you placed your **HBM** file

Comment: I am directly putting both the dtd files in my project. So that should not make any differnce. Still i channged it and its the same output.

Comment: Have you put class name as **user** or **User** check it once in **HBM** file